Possible Asbestos Contamination? Pls help
We bought a condo built in 1971 recently. We decided to remodel the place and did not like the ceilings as they resembled a popcorn ceiling. My dad is doing the renovations and didn’t think asbestos may be used in the ceilings (he thought it was just installation). However, after thinking about and doing research he found it was used in ceilings. We are getting it tested but here’s the thing: we’ve already sanded all of the ceilings. Like literally all of them that had this texture. There’s dust throughout the entire house and in the ventilation system. My dad only wore an N-95 mask and I work from home. We did the upstairs first and then had our carpets cleaned so the majority of the dust that was done up there didn’t get in the carpets. We also painted the ceilings, walls, and the floors were all covered. Downstairs, however, we did not do that. We were living there while he was doing this. Dust got everywhere even though he used plastic lining to minimize as much as possible. But we kept the AC on (obviously we weren’t thinking very well), so dust settled even upstairs. I am literally freaking out as I’m already a hypochondriac and struggling to figure out what to do. We don’t have any chunks left that need removed but what do we do?? I was breathing it all day since I work from home technically. Not as heavily as him but he did have the mask on (although I know it actually isn’t that well at preventing it). If it comes back as asbestos, are we screwed? Can this be cleaned/fixed? Do we need to hire someone to clean the dust? What do we do?

Usually asbestos needs long term(years) of exposure.  It would be good to let your doctor know so they can propose tests every so often/every few years.  Your chance of getting sick is on the low side, more of something to be aware of than worrying about everyday.

If the dust has already settled, the most effective way to prevent it from becoming airborne again is to clean it up with very damp mops and sponges. If you prevent it from becoming airborne, it can't get into your lungs. I would not hire this out and would just do it myself; if you are really paranoid, wear a mask (P100 ideally or N95)
Changing any furnace/AC filters would be a good idea no matter how the test comes back.
If it comes back positive for asbestos, you should have the ducts professionally cleaned.
As far as what you've already inhaled, sorry to say but that ship has sailed. Basically all small particles inhaled can cause cancer even if they are not asbestos. That said, all people inhale small particles frequently and most do not get lung cancer. If it comes back for asbestos, it would be a good idea to get your lungs checked per your doctor's guidance.
